# How to push 1 D array to a column

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to push 1D array to a column but Im keep getting that error "Exception: The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues." which what I understood is that I cant use setValues for 1D array, it has to be 2D array or more.

Here is my code.

```
  var range = ss.getRange(3,5,ss.getLastRow()-2).getValues();
  var qValues = [];
  for( var i=0; i<range.length; i++ ) {
    qValues.push([range[i][0]]); // index 0 = column E.
  }

  var values = ss.getRange(3,14,ss.getLastRow()-2,11).getValues(); // N3:T??
  var results = [];
  for(var i=0; i<values.length; i++ ) {
    results.push((([values[i][0]+values[i][2]+values[i][4]+values[i][6]+values[i][8]+values[i][10]])*120*qValues[i][0])/1000); // index 0 = column N, etc.
  }

   ss.getRange(3, 27,).setValues(results);
```

I tried to add

```
results.push([""]);
```

before the setValues statement but it didn't work as well

If you need more info please let me know.

Thank you

Comment: This looks very familiar,like your post from earlier today.  In that post I created a column array [[],[],[],[],...[]] using the result.push([value]);  So if you simply do the math outside of the push and push the resulting value `result.push([value]);` you you should get a column array.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) license, for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to convert your 1D array into 2D array to put it into a column. It can be done this way:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var arr_2d = arr.map(x => [x]);

console.log(arr_2d); // > [[1],[2],[3],[4]]
```

For your case the last line could be something like this:

```
ss.getRange(3, 27, results.length, results[0].length).setValues(results.map(x => [x]));
```

But I don't know if your array is a valid array and what the range you want to fill. Probably in your case the array is not array at all.

Could you show the contents of the array `results`?

```
console.log(results)
```

Because this operation looks extremely weird:

```
([ values[i][0] + 
   values[i][2] + 
   values[i][4] + 
   values[i][6] + 
   values[i][8] + 
   values[i][10] ]) * 120 * qValues[i][0]
```

I frankly don't understand what you're trying to gain.

Perhaps there shouldn't be the brackets `[...]`:

```
( values[i][0] + 
  values[i][2] + 
  values[i][4] + 
  values[i][6] + 
  values[i][8] + 
  values[i][10] ) * 120 * qValues[i][0]
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Flat array to column

```
function flatArraytoColumn() {
  let a = [...Array.from(new Array(10).keys(), x => [x + 1])];//second term of array.from returns each element in an array
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet()
  sh.getRange(1, 1, a.length, 1).setValues(a);//Post into column
  Logger.log(a);//log array
}

Execution log
1:07:57 PM  Notice  Execution started
1:07:58 PM  Info    [[1.0], [2.0], [3.0], [4.0], [5.0], [6.0], [7.0], [8.0], [9.0], [10.0]]
1:07:59 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Active Sheet:

[image]